# How to find all subtrees, given a Linked binary tree in java, or even a regular binary tree?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, subtree

I encountered an interview question that required me to create a method to find all subtrees within a binary tree. I was unable to figure it out, how would I go about answering this question? Is there an easy way to implement this using recursion? should i traverse the list?
any advice is greatly appreciated!

I have only written so far a generic node class:

```java
public class Node<Object> 
{
    private Object data ;
    private Node<Object> left ; 
    private Node<Object> right ; 


    public Node()
    {
        this(null,null,null) ; 
    }        


    public Node(Object D, Node<Object> L, Node<Object> R)
    {
        data = D ;
        left = L ; 
        right = R ; 
    }


    public Object getData()
    {
        return data ; 
    }        


    public void setData(Object d)
    {
        data = d ; 
    }        


    public Node<Object> getLeft() 
    {
        return left ; 
    }        

   public Node<Object> getRight()
    {
        return right ; 
    }   

    public void setLeft(Node node)
    {
        left = node ; 
    }



    public void setRight(Node node)
    {
        right = node ; 
    }        
}
```

any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Much depends on what it means to "find" a subtree.  There is one rooted at each node, so simply identifying or counting them all just amounts to finding all the nodes.  Your choice of depth-first or breadth-first traversal of the tree should suffice for that.

If "finding" a subtree means doing something particular to or with it, then that could make one of those two traversal strategies more appropriate than the other.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, what I'm trying to do basically is given a binary tree, I would like to return all the subtrees within that tree

Comment: for example i have :                                                                    26
            /   \
          10     3
        /    \     \
      4       6      3
       \
        30     . so it would return (26,10, 3) and (10,4,6) etc... sorry for the layout im having trouble editing this comment

Comment: What you are describing are not "subtrees" in the conventional sense, but that doesn't actually change my answer.  You just walk the tree -- your choice of depth-first or breadth-first -- and collect the subtree, if any, rooted at each node.  I am not going to write the code for you, as that would defeat your instructor's purpose in assigning you this homework.